# Additional empty line in right-click menu

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus

For unknown reason an additional empty line at the very bottom (below "Properties") is displayed in the context menu that appears when I right-click on a directory in Nautilus - see the screenshot below (this does not happen for files, only for directories). This was not happening previously, I don't know why it started to happen. This looks ugly and I want to get rid of this. Do you have any idea what the reason for this empty line may be & how to remove it?

Nautilus version is 3.36.3-stable.

**UPDATE:** Temporarily, the issue went away by itself (???) and I didn't have that empty line anymore. Can't correlate this with anything I possibly did, because I did nothing special, just regular use of the computer. But when I booted my computer next time, the empty line is again there...

[image]

Comment: Since i do not read this language and this is an English only site I can not find the properties or see the empty line for that matter.

Comment: @David "Properties" is usually the last position in the context menu, regardless of language, and the empty line is directly below it.

Comment: Please provide version name of the file manager: ≡ About files (last item in that menu)

Comment: @vanadium 3.36.3-stable . Added to question.

Comment: @raj My properties in Nautilus has two empty lines sprinkled in the body and about 8 empty lines at the end. Your newer Nautilus (aka Files)  is a step up in that respect. Plus yours even display more properties than mine does. A quick search on your issue didn't reveal any bug reports. Personally I wouldn't care so maybe you are the only person this bugs?